# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I've installed XAMPP and have been attempting to interrogate my database using PHP although I keep getting the same error.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "secret";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Perform queries 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "use edgeserver; call ShowAll") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

  //loop the result set
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
     echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1]; 
  }

$conn->close();

?>
```

However this presents me with the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\ShowAll.php on line 16
Query fail:
```

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. `mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter...` and that is the connection. Like  `mysqli_error($conn);` You can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Mysql_error requires db connection to be passed. Try below:

```
mysqli_error($conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it ended up being a combination of what you both said:

```
<?php   

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'edgeserver');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Perform queries 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "call ShowAll") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

  //loop the result set
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
     echo $row[0] . " - " . + $row[1]; 
  }

$conn->close();
```

Great response, hopefully this will be the base to me developing some good code.

Comment: control mysqli error handling: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from `use edgeserver; call ShowAll`.

`use edgeserver`, where edgeserver is the database that you want to use.
`call ShowAll` - what you try to accomplish with this?

Your new mysqli must be like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

source: http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.construct.php

And on mysqli_query you must do the queries like "Select * from table".

Comment: With [`call ShowAll`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) he wants to execute [stored procedure](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php). You might be right about specifying the database in mysqli creation, not in the query.